# Short-circuited boolean binary operators in Haskell

Tags: haskell, boolean, interpreter, short-circuiting

I'm building a call by name Haskell interpreter and I want to implement a function `short :: Val -> Exp -> Error Val` that will evaluate a value applied to an expression. I don't want to evaluate the second arguments of the short-circuited boolean binary operators (i.e. `((&&) False)` and `((||) True))`, nor the argument passed to a unit lambda (`\() -> ...`) abstraction.

In a lazy language such as Haskell, I know you get short circuited boolean binary operators built into the Prelude. I was thinking that its possible to do something like this:

```
short :: Val -> Exp -> Error Val
short (Partial (&&) False) = False
-- Making use of Partial Oper Val that is defined in Val
```

But I already know that a type error will arise. I'm not sure what to exactly do. Any suggestions?

Some additional definitions:

```
data Val = VUnit | VNil
         | VN Int | VB Bool | VOp Oper
         | Partial Oper Val
         | VLamUnit Exp (Env Val)
         | VLam String Exp (Env Val)
         | VListBool [Bool]
         | VListInt [Int]

data Exp = Unit | Nil
         | N Int | B Bool | Var String | Op Oper
         | App Exp Exp
         | LamUnit Exp
         | Lam String Exp
         | If Exp Exp Exp
         | Let [(String, Exp)] Exp

data Error a = S a
             | Error String
```

Comment: Could you provide more code, like how `Val` and `Exp` are defined. This is not much to go on.

Comment: The code gives us very little idea of what you're trying to do there. Why would you use `&&` as a pattern here? Ignoring the fact that `((&&) False)` is not a syntactically legal pattern, `&&` is Haskell's operator, not your languages. Shouldn't you be matching against whatever representation you have for your language's && operator?

Comment: sorry about that. i have included definitions for `Val` and `Exp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evaluation of the arguments of a function is first determined by the patterns used to bind the arguments.

If you have

```
short :: Val -> Exp -> Error Val
short val ex
   | condition on val only       = something
   | other condition on val only = somethingElse
   | condition involving ex too  = thirdPossibility
   | otherwise                   = whatever
```

no evaluation takes place on binding the arguments, since the patterns are irrefutable variable patterns, `val` is - partially or maybe completely - evaluated to determine the outcome of the first guard. If that evaluates to `True`, `exp` is only evaluated if it is used in `something` and its evaluation is necessary to evaluate `something`. Only if the first two conditions evaluate to `False`, `ex` is evaluated to determine the value of the third guard (and maybe not even then).

If you can shortcut based on the constructor of `val`, you can use a refutable pattern for `val` and let `ex` be a variable pattern (just an identifier), you get the same short-circuiting as for `(&&)` etc.

```
short (Val foo) ex = Okay (foo bar ex)
short (Lav oof) _  = Okay oof
short val ex
  | isGood val = oomph
  | isBad ex   = error "Didn't expect that"
  | otherwise  = undefined
```

If you don't use the `Exp` argument on the right hand side, you don't even need to give it a name, the wildcard `_` says "here is an argument that shall be ignored".

For your desired behaviour of

```
short :: Val -> Exp -> Error Val
short (Partial (&&) False) = False
```

that as such doesn't work because `False` is a `Bool` and not a `Val`, you can use

```
short (Partial OR (VB False)) _ = S False
```

with a hypothetical constructor `OR` of `Oper`. (You can use `(&&)` there, but that is a variable pattern matching anything.) That pattern doesn't even bind the `Exp` argument, so unless its evaluation has been forced by previous equations for `short`, it remains unevaluated.